# Function on perl doesn't work

Tags: perl, function

I have a function:

```
my $descr = 'Rand [Hi|Hello|Aloha] [Kate|Ann|Polly]';
print intrp($descr);

sub intrp($str)
{

my $str =~ s{
    \[ ( [^\]]* ) \]
}{
    my @choices = split /\|/, $1;
    $choices[rand(@choices)]
}xeg;

return $str;
}
```

Why it doesn't work?=\ I tried some other methods, but they didn't help me

Comment: D:\Scripts>1.pl After running I don't receive anything

Comment: Oh, yes, that clears _everything_ up.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *never* use prototypes on Perl subroutine declarations. They do something very specific, and unless you know what that is you should avoid them completely. In particular named prototypes aren't yet supported by any verion of Perl

You should also *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every program. It will highlight easily-overlooked errors that otherwise may take a while to fix, and is common courtesy before you ask others for help with your program

This version of your code seems to work correctly

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $descr = 'Rand [Hi|Hello|Aloha] [Kate|Ann|Polly]';
print intrp($descr);

sub intrp {

  my ($str) = @_;

  $str =~ s{ \[ ( [^\]]* ) \] }{
      my @choices = split /\|/, $1;
      $choices[rand(@choices)]
  }xeg;

  return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subroutine should look like this:

```
sub intrp
{
 my ($str) = @_;
 $str =~ s{
....
```

Not:

```
sub intrp($str)
...
```

Comment: actually like this: sub intrp {...}